# Arch on eeePC 901

Tags: arch-linux

My old eeePC901 has Intel Atom CPU N270 @ 1.60GHz x 2 processor. This processor is neither i686 nor x86_64, as far as I understand.

I was looking for an operating system that would run quickly on my computer and I learnt about Arch.

[ArchWiki FAQ](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Frequently_asked_questions#Will_I_have_all_the_packages_from_my_32-bit_Arch.3F) says:

> You may not want to use Arch, if you require support for an architecture other than x86_64 or i686.

However, there is [evidence](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ASUS_Eee_PC_901) that some people successfully install Arch on their eeePC 901.

**Is it a good idea to install Arch on my eeePC 901 despite the fact that it is not x86_64 and not i686?**

**Is there any other alternative operating system that would make my computer run quickly?**

Initially I had Windows XP and it was terribly slow. Then I changed to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS which was better but still quite slow. Now I am looking for something quicker.

Comment: I think your problem is not about the OS is slow, but the browser is slow.
Intel atom is slightly less than x64, so we can call it i686.

Comment: The browser is slow indeed. But there is not much I can do about it, is there? Still I'd like my computer to load faster and open programs faster.

Comment: Firefox, chrome, opera, etc. are the same code and independent from which distro running it. It will be the same slow on all linux distributions. If you ask for a fast desktop environment, then use `icewm`. It's really fast.

Comment: Well, thanks for the hint. I'll check out icewm.